# PyWebview not connecting to locally running websocket server

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, webview

I have a project running which uses websockets to transfer data from my python code (an OpenCV project) to a front end. The front-end is written in regular HTML/CSS/JS and the websocket server is written in NodeJS.

When I run the UI in a browser, it works perfectly and the data gets sent. However, if I run it using python's webview module, it doesn't seem to work. I am not able to access the console to view any errors that are occurring in the webview window so I am not sure why this is happening.

This is the websocket code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8000 });

const clients = new Map();

wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
    const id = uuidv4();
    const color = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
    const metadata = { id, color };

    clients.set(ws, metadata);

    ws.on('message', (messageAsString) => {
    const message = JSON.parse(messageAsString);
    const metadata = clients.get(ws);

    message.sender = metadata.id;
    message.color = metadata.color;   
    
    const outbound = JSON.stringify(message);

      [...clients.keys()].forEach((client) => {
        client.send(outbound);
      });
    }); 

    ws.on("close", () => {
        clients.delete(ws);
    });
});    

function uuidv4() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}
console.log("wss up");
```

This is the front-end JS code that handles incoming websocket messages:

```
window.addEventListener('load',e=>{
    var check = 0;
    var fail = 0;
    (async function() {
        const ws = await connectToServer();


        ws.onmessage = (webSocketMessage) => {
            console.log("WS Message recieved")
            const messageBody = JSON.parse(webSocketMessage.data);
            console.log(messageBody)
            
            var type = messageBody.type
            var _data = messageBody.data
            // handle the data here
        };    
        async function connectToServer() {
            const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/ws');
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const timer = setInterval(() => {
                    if(ws.readyState === 1) {
                        clearInterval(timer)
                        resolve(ws);
                    }
                }, 10);
            });
        } 

    })();            
})
```

The webview code:

```
import webview

webview.create_window("GUI", "http://localhost:8080", resizable=True, fullscreen=True)
webview.start()
```

Keep in mind that when I run it from the browser it works perfectly so I know the messages do get sent. It is something to do about running it through python webview that causes the problem.

What seems to be reason for this problem and how do I fix it?